# WebView content interaction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-animation, android-imageview

so this is what I have and what I want to achieve.

I have WebView component, which loads website with images.
I want to be able to grab some image from website, and animate a move (cloning) of that image into my existing ImageView (replace the image source) with appropriate scaling, so that my ImageView looks loaded from WebView.

Any idea how to do that, and to have a nice and smooth animation effect.

My idea was to create bitmap from URL loaded from WebView and to animate that bitmap over the screen, but that took some time by the time I download the image and convert it to new bitmap, so I can't have smooth effect with that approach.

So any other idea?

Comment: why dont use javascript?

Comment: that was my initial idea, to pass url from javascript to my java method, but by the time I download the image based from that URL and create bitmap app will be frozen, so I won't have nice and smooth animation affect, there will be delay...